# How do you delete a mailbox from your Yahoo app on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, email, yahoo

I have an iPhone 8 running the latest version of the yahoo mail app (4.37)

In the app, I can either "Add another mailbox" or add another account thru "Manage Accounts"

I initially added my account as a mailbox through the "Add another mailbox" link.  It added my account/mailbox but didn't load all my emails.  I then clicked "Manage Accounts" and added my account.

Going thru "Manage Accounts" to add my account shows all my emails.  Now, I want to delete the mailbox that was created.  However, I can't seem to do so.  I even went through "Manage Accounts" to delete the account, hoping that it would remove both the mailbox and account but it didn't.

I followed the directions on Yahoo's website but [those instructions didn't work](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN22048.html)

I also tried adding my gmail account (as a test to delete it) thru the Yahoo mail app as a mailbox.  I'm running into the same problem, I can't delete my gmail account/mailbox either.

Hopefully someone can help me.  Thanks.

UPDATE: Deleting the app didn't work.  The mailboxes are still here.
I also tried going to my Iphone Settings->Yahoo Mail->Reset All Accounts.  Also didn't work.  Both my gmail account and that rogue yahoo account is still there.

Answer (score 1):

From Yahoo's site:

1. Tap the Menu icon Image of the Sidebar menu icon..
2. Tap Manage Accounts.
3. Tap Account info below the Yahoo Mail account that's linked.
4. Tap the X beside the linked account. <- I assume you did this, and it did not delete.
5. Tap Unlink to confirm.

From: 
https://help.yahoo.com/kb/add-remove-email-accounts-yahoo-mail-sln26459.html (your link took me to different document...)

If the account doesn't go away via the Yahoo delete instructions, I think you should look for sending a report to Yahoo.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Manage Accounts - Under your primary account, you'll see an Account Info hyperlink.  Click on that and it will take you to a secondary screen.  At the bottom is where you'll see the x next to all of your linked accounts. Select the one you don't want and it will unlink from there.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I went to manage accounts and settings but nothing appeared. But I figured it out. You go to settings-> manage mailboxes and delete there.

If it doesn’t show up, like I think it did for me, delete the app and reinstall it. Go to settings again and sure enough right under manage accounts would be manage mailboxes.

Hope this helps people in the future.

[image: ![[Yahoo screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yqqM.jpg)]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E26zD.png)